# changing color for CHeaderCtrl of a list view

Tags: listview, mfc

Is there a graceful way of changing the background color
 of the header control of a list view
*retaining* the shade and look of headers in list views in windows xp+?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can look [skinlist](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/skinlist.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/filterheaderctrl.aspx) it can be usefull